# Detect image tilt angle and fix without system.drawing library in azure function c#.net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, emgucv, system.drawing

Is there any way/library for rotation and fix the image tilt without using **system.drawing** as I am using azure function so it is not supported.

I am using *c#.net core2.1*.

I tried **Emgu.CV** 
It has following 2 function which internally uses system.drawing

```
LineSegment2D(Point p1, Point p2)
RotationMatrix2D(PointF center, double angle, double scale)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [SixLabors.ImageSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/1.0.0-beta0007), and please refer to this [tutorial](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing.RotateExtensions.html) for rotate operation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using EmguCV in a netCore 2.1 project and it works for me. netCore does support a [subset of System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?view=netcore-2.1). These are all parts which are not using GDI/GDI+. As long as you do not use Bitmap class or any EmguCV methods that use Bitmap as parameter you are fine.